# Iframe Image default zoom out issue

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am loading an image through iframe and have removed default styling of zoom and auto-scrolling. Now I am facing issue in showing image in IE and Chrome when the image dimension is 1024*768(when picking up image from the Sample Picture of windows) and it is working fine for smaller dimension picture 200*100. The problem is only part of the image is showing up. I guess it is the zoom issue of chrome and ie. Please help me in counter this issue.

Code which I have done for IFrame is

```
<div class="dataGroup inline-inputs" >  
<label for="_erCurrentLogo">Current Logo:</label>
<iframe id="imgLogo"  frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<a id="deleteEmployerLogo" href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="deleteLogo();return false">delete</a> 
</div>
```

[image: Pic issue comping up in Chrome and IE]
[image: Pic issue comping up in Chrome and IE]

Comment: You need to show the entire picture instead of showing a part. Am I correct?

Comment: Right. I need to show entire picture.

Comment: Does your web page(iframe) contains anything else than the picture?

Comment: yes, it contains file uploader element apart from showing image.

Comment: Your external page page contains only a image tag and file uploader, And from that you want to display only the image. Is that so?

Comment: Yes, your assumptions are right

Answer (score 1):

This is my suggestion for your issue;

I guess you have set `width` and `height` for the iframe.  (below is the sample code I used)

```
#imgLogo  
{   
    width:200px;  
    height:100px;  
}
```

Use that same `height` and `width` for the image in your `iframe` referenced page.

```
img  
{   
    width:200px;  
    height:100px;  
}
```

Only thing you have to do is make the `image` and `iframe` **height and width** to same.

[image: sample]

Comment: If this is not help you, please update your post with more details(css used, iframe referenced page[html,css])

Comment: Thanks @New. But the problem is I dont know the size of uploaded file before. so I cant hardcode width and height of iframe and image to same.

Comment: As per your say, it is working for smaller size pictures but breaking for larger size picture. For dimensions 1024*768, only part of the image is showing up. Please pick any picture from the Windows default picture folder.

Comment: I used the same image you have used from the windows pictures folder.

Comment: Actually the image that i uploaded here is of lesser dimension. Pick any picture from yours windows pictures folder which are of higher dimensions.

Comment: this is the image I used from my windows pics Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Chrysanthemum.jpg. And  its dimension is 1024x768. But did not getting the issue you are pointing. :(

Comment: The thing is I am setting the iframe height and width on page load because i dont know what dimensions of image user going to upload and you have provided dimensions statically.

Comment: If you can please update your issue with compete code. Then I can get clear understanding on your issue.